# HandleAuthenticateAsync called even without [Authorize] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorize-attribute

I'm using a custom `AuthenticationHandler` and only some of my controller methods have the `[Authorize]` attribute. I log on Info level and it creates a log entry for *any* method call. Now I can't tell apart if somebody actually tried accessing a method that requires authorization and failed or if it's a call to a method that doesn't even need authorization and it fails because it's supposed to.

Is there a way to tell them apart or preferably to keep MVC from calling `HandleAuthenticateAsync` when it's not needed?

Comment: I am facing same issue, so what exactly worked for you.

Comment: @Satindersingh Look at the differences of Authentication and Authorization. I had to switch to Authorization because what I was doing is much more Authorizing than Authenticating.

Comment: It is bit late. But I solved this by add check in the beginning of HandleAuthenticateAsynce
var endpoint= Context.GetEndPoint();
if(endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymouse()!=null || endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<IAuthorizeData>() = null)
{
return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
}

Idea is to return immediately No result if there is AllowAnonymous or no Authorize attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you might be misusing the `AuthenticationHandler`. You are not supposed to immediately reject access if the user fails to authenticate. If you do so, it doesn't even reach the MVC context in the pipeline.

Unless you intentionally want to reject any access to unauthenticated users, you should only either authenticate or pass it through as anonymous user. After that at some point `AuthorizeAttribute` will kick in and check whether user has access to the requested resource or not. If he is not authenticated, the authorization will reject the request.

Comment: Just to be clear, technically the `Controller`s have `[Authorize]` and some methods have `[AllowAnonymous]`. And if a method with `[AllowAnonymous]` is being called, it works just fine, but for each call I get a log message telling me the authentication failed.

Comment: @lennyy but that is the desired behavior because authentication is performed before MVC kicks in, that is, before even any controller is created and authorization attributes are processed.

Comment: Oh my god I just now noticed I'm using a `AUTHENTICATIONHandler`... Is there such a thing as `AuthorizationHandler`?

Comment: @lennyy technically handlers are not suitable for that as authorization is done after all the handlers have fully completed and the MVC context is created. You should use [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#authorization-filters) for the purpose.

Comment: @lenny yes there is an AuthorizationHandler class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-7.0